# Trying to embed if inside of other if's

Tags: javascript

This one is just waaay too far over my head. I can tell where each starts and ends, but all the extra stuff after the commas is messing me up.
I have the following code I am trying to modify to add another query section to:

```
if (typeof ShellInABox == "function") {
    clearInterval(window.loginInterval);
    window.shell = new ShellInABox();
    if (getQueryVariable("u")){
      setTimeout(function(){
        enterWord(getQueryVariable("u"))
        if (getQueryVariable("p")){
          setTimeout(function(){
              enterWord(getQueryVariable("p"));
              window.autologinpassword="";
          },getQueryVariable("d") || 2000);
        }
      }, 2000);
    }
  }
```

I need to add another section like..

```
if (getQueryVariable("c")){
  setTimeout(function(){
    enterWord(getQueryVariable("c"))
```

..after the password is sent. but every way I try doesn't work. And I am killing changing it, zip, scp, unzip, recompile/make/install, and then testing. Been banging my head on the desk on this for 2 hours. Can't figure out why after one of the enterWord sections it has a semicolon, but the other doesn't.. Please help.

Comment: It's not clear why all these timeouts are necessary? Btw, the first `enterWord` could have a `;` as well (and I would put it), but with or without shouldn't change anything.

Comment: If `getQueryVariable()` returns a numeric value that is 0 or anything falsey the the `if(){}` statements fail. I cannot tell what your code is doing, or what your goal is, with what has been provided for us.

Comment: I am using code from a forked copy of shellinabox from github. The whole point is to be able to pass 192.168.1.5/?u=user1&p=mypass to be able to automate the login to this shell.  The u and p options were added in this fork, and as far as I can tell, this is the relevant code where I can add another option like u and p, called c, which will hopefully run after the first 2. I have tested the code as is, and it works fine. I believe the timeouts are since this is embedding a bash shell in a webpage essentially, and depending on connections speeds, might need a pause between passing user and pass

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

1. Click the end of the line before the end of an if statement, and before the set time out call.
2. Hit enter, or return, for each one, to make the code easier to understand.

Good luck.

Comment: This helped. I took it a step farther, and just removed section by section that I didn't understand, which were the setTimeouts.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got it after just stripping it all down to bare if statements multiple times:

```
if (getQueryVariable("u")){
          setTimeout(function(){
            enterWord(getQueryVariable("u"))
            if (getQueryVariable("p")){
              setTimeout(function(){
                  enterWord(getQueryVariable("p"));
                  if (getQueryVariable("c")){
                    enterWord(getQueryVariable("c"));
                    }
              }, 2000);
            }
          }, 2000);
        }
```

What was screwing me up was the || in the middle of one of them.  The logic to this section is this:

If there is an option u specified, set a timeout of 2 seconds, then run the function enterWord with the value of u. If there is an option p, set a timeout of 2 seconds OR the value of option d, then run enterWord.  After 30 or so revisions of this, I finally got it working after I tore it apart to base functionality, then figured out why timeouts would be needed, and how to add them in.  Time to go have a few drinks.